# A generic way of logging text of clicked controls in .NET application?

Tags: .net, events, logging, controls, mouse

Is there a generic way of doing it? I want to log all mouse-click events of my application without placing code in each event handler. I want to log text of the clicked item too. In 80% of cases, clicked items would be tree nodes and context menu items.

Comment: What are you targetting? Winforms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: What type of application are you running e.g. windows, web, aps, silverlight/WPF etc?

Comment: It is a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the tree control and wrap the click event, it would call your logger and then proceed with the click.

While it's a pain, it's good practice to wrap all controls at the beginning of the project because requirements like this seem to always come up at the eleventh hour and then your not stuck doing a major refactor.